# "bun x create-next-app" is stuck at the second question

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, bun

If I try to run the command "bun x create-next-app" in WSL Ubuntu, I get stuck at the second question "Would you like to use TypeScript? › No / Yes" and I cannot press anything.

Why could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue on the `bun` project already.

Find it here: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/4664

This is probably going to be fixed, and is an issue with interactivity.
So instead, you can opt-out from interactivity, and provide everything the CLI needs.

For example:

```
create-next-app <your-project-name> --ts --tailwind --eslint --app --src-dir --use-bun --import-alias "@/*"
```

Also see: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app#non-interactive

**Update:** fix it by doing a `bun upgrade` to version `1.0.2`.